# How do I add an icon to a mingw-gcc compiled executable?

Tags: windows, gcc, icons, mingw

In Windows, using mingw's gcc, is there anyway to specify that the output exe file is to take an icon file, so that the exe file shows with that icon in explorer?

Answer (score 215):

You need to create the icon first. Then you need to create a RC file with the below content. Here we'll name it as `my.rc`.

```
id ICON "path/to/my.ico"
```

The `id` mentioned in the above command can be pretty much anything. It doesn't matter unless you want to refer to it in your code. Then run windres as follows:

```
windres my.rc -O coff -o my.res
```

Then while building the executable, along with other object files and resource files, include `my.res` which we got from the above step. e.g.:

```
g++ -o my_app obj1.o obj2.o res1.res my.res
```

And that should be all there is to it.

---

And, at no extra charge, if you want to include version information in your
application, add the following boilerplate to a new `.rc` file and follow the above mentioned steps.

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION  1,0,0,0
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "080904E4"
    BEGIN
      VALUE "CompanyName", "My Company Name"
      VALUE "FileDescription", "My excellent application"
      VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0"
      VALUE "InternalName", "my_app"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright", "My Name"
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", "my_app.exe"
      VALUE "ProductName", "My App"
      VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0"
    END
  END
  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x809, 1252
  END
END
```

Note, the langID is for U.K. English (which is the closest localisation to
Australia I could identify.) If you want U.S. "English" then change the `BLOCK`
line to:

```
BLOCK "040904E4"
```

and the translation line to:

```
VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
```

See [VERSIONINFO resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/versioninfo-resource) for for info.

Comment: It would be great if the example showed where to insert the ICON line.

Comment: And... secondly..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411040/how-to-add-an-icon-to-an-application-built-with-eclipse-galileo-c-and-mingw

Comment: you can also include multiple "Translations" (it's just telling Windows that this program is translated) by just appending WORD, WORD-pairs, for example: `VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252, 0x809, 1252` would enable both US and UK English according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058.aspx. This also tells you that you can include more than one 'BLOCK "lang04E4"'

Comment: I used Nirsoft's free utility `IconsExtract` to get an icon embedded in an `exe` that I needed.

Comment: Where do you get `windres`?  I've got `binutils-mingw-w64-i686` already installed, but windres is not found.

Comment: @endolith in MSYS2 package you need to run console command `pacman -S mingw-w64-cross-binutils`. Or get one from [MingW-W64-builds](https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/MingW-W64-builds) - it's in the `/mingw64/bin` directory, which I like to have in PATH envvar. Also check differences between `i686` and `86_64`, because the one you got is for 32-bit systems.

Answer (score 6):

In the RC file, the *nameID* does not even have to be a name, it can just be
an integer. The *filename* must be quoted only if it contains a space. Instead
of:

```
windres my.rc -O coff -o my.res
```

You can use:

```
windres my.rc my.o
```

- [ICON resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa381018)
- [windres man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/windres.1.html)
- [Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/rosso/blob/8e151be/rosso.rc)

Comment: I couldn't link the `my.o` with MinGW's `g++` after `windres my.rc my.o` (some `WinMain`-related error message), but the `windres my.rc -O coff -o my.res` path worked fine.

Comment: `.o` (= COFF automatically; I name it like `my.res.o` for clarity) works for me. Actually `.res` files as produced by MSVC have a different format, so it seems to be odd/incompatible using COFF in `.res`

Answer (score 3):

Try Resource Hacker.  I was able to cross compile my project in Linux (WSL) and generate an icon from the logo on the homepage.  Just needed a simple way to embed it in the exe and this program worked great.
[Resource Hacker by Angus Johnson](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Comment: This was way easier.  Just opened the .exe, clicked "Add Binary or Image Resource", opened the .ico file, and saved.