# How do I add an icon to my C++ compiled executable when using Eclipse?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

So i'm creating a small program and I want to use a custom icon for it's .exe. I'm using the Microsoft Visual C++ toolchain in Eclipse.C/C++ Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out! I created a file called icon.rc and added the following line:

`id ICON "\path\to\icon.ico"`

It automatically compiled it and added it to my executable.

Answer (score 0):

Executable icons are handled differently for different operating systems.
I assume that you are writing a Windows C++ program (your question doesn't have a tag for your target OS or OSes).
In Windows, the icon is stored in a "resource", which can be separate or part of your executable.

I think a little reading is necessary on your part, though I'll offer search suggestions:

- visual c++ [version] resource editor
- eclipse windows resource icon

Comment: There exist a similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411040/how-to-add-an-icon-to-an-application-built-with-eclipse-galileo-c-and-mingw