# Win32 LoadBitmap returns Error 1814

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been trying to get `LoadBitmap()` to work for some time now. It's returning error 1814, `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`. Code below, but so far I've tried:

- Using `(HBITMAP)LoadImage()` instead of `LoadBitmap()`
- Using `MAKEINTRESOURCE('ICON.BMP')` instead of the resource idenfitier
- Changing the filename, resource idenfitier name and resource type of the bitmap, as well as trying it with full path name or file name only
- Using `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` instead of passing the instance handle to the function
- Separating `MAKEINTRESOURCE` and putting it behind its own error check just to make sure the problem isn't there (it's not)
- Checking compiler and linker for updates
- Stepping through the debugger

I've also been through every SO question I could find about this, other sites, MSDN documentation, and tried applying what I found there, to no avail. What am I missing?

Using MinGW on Eclipse

resource.rc

```
#include "resource.h"

IDBMP_TREEICON BITMAP "icon.bmp"
```

resource.h

```
#ifndef __RESOURCE_H_INCLUDED__
#define __RESOURCE_H_INCLUDED__

#define IDBMP_TREEICON 101

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <string>
#include "resource.h"

BOOL InitTreeViewImage(HINSTANCE hInstance, HWND hWnd){
    HBITMAP hbmp = NULL;
    HIMAGELIST hImgList;

    if((hImgList = ImageList_Create(10, 10, FALSE, 1, 0)) == NULL){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create ImageList!", "Eror", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    LPCSTR theBitmap = NULL;
    theBitmap = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDBMP_TREEICON);
    if(theBitmap == NULL){
        //GetLastError(), output to console, messagebox - removed for brevity in this example
        return false;
    }

    hbmp = LoadBitmap(hInstance, theBitmap);
    if(hbmp == NULL){
        //GetLastError(), output to console, messagebox - removed for brevity in this example
        return false;
    }
    treeIcon = ImageList_Add(hImgList, hbmp, NULL);
    if(treeIcon == 1){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to add icon to image list!", "Eror", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    DeleteObject(hbmp);

    TreeView_SetImageList(hWnd, hImgList, TVSIL_NORMAL);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try open the .exe file with a resource browser (e.g. visual studio).  This should show if the resource is being compiled into the .exe, or being missed off.

Comment: Your suggestion led me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411040/how-to-add-an-icon-to-an-application-built-with-eclipse-galileo-c-and-mingw
I tried a few variations of that, still no luck. This is the second time I've been told to switch to Visual Studio, so I guess I'd better do it. Will edit when I have some sort of result.

Comment: Show the build commands and output.  This sure seems like the resources didn't get linked to the module or you're using the wrong HINSTANCE.

Comment: I finally had a chance to try all of this in Visual Studio 2015. It builds and compiles, but the error message is now "The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file", which I take to be Visual Studio's version of g++'s error 1814, which is what I was getting before. My resource appears to be set up correctly though.

Answer (score 5):

When `LoadBitmap` fails with `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`, that means the module you specify has no resource of type `RT_BITMAP` with the resource ID that you supplied. It is absolutely that simple.

There are many possible failure modes:

- You supplied the wrong module. Check that `hInstance` really does identify the correct module that you linked the resource to.
- The resource that you linked has the wrong type, or the wrong ID. That seems quite unlikely given what you present in the question.
- You failed to pass the compiled resource file to the linker, and no resource was actually linked to the executable.

As an aside, `MAKEINTRESOURCE` is a simple macro, and it's a mistake to expect `GetLastError()` to return anything related to `MAKEINTRESOURCE`. As a hard rule, only ever use `GetLastError()` if the documentation explicitly says that it is meaningful to do so.

Comment: I've tried this with an instance handle passed from the main function, a global instance handle, and GetInstanceHandle(NULL), with no perceptible change in results. Is there anything else I should be trying?

Comment: Use a resource editor program to check that the resource is linked correctly.