# Problems with adding Icon to executable (Eclipse CDT Luna): make: *** No rule to make target 'resources.o'

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411040/how-to-add-an-icon-to-an-application-built-with-eclipse-galileo-c-and-mingw) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable) to add an Icon to my Executable

I am getting Error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'resources.o', needed by 'Project_Name'.  Stop.
```

I have:
- created resources.h
- created resources.rc (Already checked that path inside file is correct)
- added #include "resources.h" to my main.cpp
- added prebuilt option

```
  windres ../resources.rc -O coff -o ../resources.o
```

- added linker object resources.o

Still looks like something is missing. The files resource.rc and resource.h are included in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution myself.
Eclipse builds following directory structure:

project_name
 - Release
 - Debug
 - .settings

Because gcc/g++ is called to build .o files in the Release/Debug folder, and .cpp and .h files are in project_name the same must go with .rc files - seems like I have mistaken the folders in linked explanation

I put resource.rc and .ico in project_name, and as with .cpp I am making .o files one folder below

So this is the right command in
Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Build Steps->Pre-build->Command

```
windres ../resources.rc -O coff -o  ./resources.o
```

and in
Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Linker->Miscellaneous->Other objects
add 'resource.o'

And most important: **to avoid 'no rule to make target' none of mentioned files should be added to the project**