# How to make Eclipse recognize and build .rc (Windows resource) files through MinGW windres?

Tags: c++, eclipse, winapi, eclipse-cdt

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411040/how-to-add-an-icon-to-an-application-built-with-eclipse-galileo-c-and-mingw) and [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/53724/), but it all looks ugly because it blocks pre-build command field for the later use and works for only one file.
Is there a way to make it smarter, like setting default action for all *.rc files?

Comment: What about providing your own makefile instead of letting eclipse generate it? You could provide a rule for handling `.rc` files.

Comment: does eclipse allow editing his makefile generation rules such way?
because i'm not going to edit makefile manually each time

Comment: @KarashevichB. You either write the entire makefile (in which case you need to create a Makefile project), or you have Eclipse generate the makefile (this is called a Managed Build project), in which case you can use the pre-build step approach.