# Applying Visual Studio version information file to MinGW G++

Tags: windows, c++11, g++, mingw32

I am trying to apply my version information file created using Visual Studio (.rc file) to my executable that I am compiling and linking using mingw32-g++.exe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add an icon to a mingw-gcc compiled executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable)

Comment: While the _question_ isn't a duplicate per se, the _answer_ given there is perfectly applicable to your question.