# unable to add icon to exe using windres

Tags: windows, gcc, icons, mingw, windres

I'd like to add an Icon to my exe compiled with mingw-gcc.

I followed instructions in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable) but the Icon does not show up on my exe in windows explorer.

**[edit]** 
Meanwhile I found out that `windres` destroys my executable. Before applying windres the executable runs as expected. After applying `windres`  calling the executable results in a windows error message telling (roughly) that this executable is not compatible with this windows version.

What am I doing wrong?

---

This is my directory layout:

```
$ ls -lR launcher/
launcher/:
total 508
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089      0 Aug 20  2015 src/
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089      0 Nov  7 10:56 target/

launcher/src:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089 0 Nov  7 10:51 main/

launcher/src/main:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089 0 Nov  7 10:52 cpp/
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089 0 Apr 14  2016 resources/
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089 0 Nov  4 15:11 scripts/

launcher/src/main/cpp:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 1049089 6793 Nov  7 10:41 JavaLauncher.cpp

launcher/src/main/resources:
total 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 1049089   47 Nov  7 10:47 javaLauncher.rc
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 1049089 2238 Apr 14  2016 JavaLauncher.ico

launcher/src/main/scripts:
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 1049089 389 Nov  7 10:56 makefile

launcher/target:
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089 2502 Nov  7 10:56 JavaLauncher.exe*
```

this is my resource file:

```
0 ICON "launcher/src/main/resources/JavaLauncher.ico"
```

this is my makefile:

```
all: launcher/target/JavaLauncher.exe

launcher/target/JavaLauncher.exe: launcher/src/main/cpp/JavaLauncher.cpp launcher\target
    /Absolute/Path/to/mingw64/bin/g++.exe $< -o $@ -static -l winpthread
    /Absolute/Path/to/mingw64/bin/windres.exe -v -i launcher/src/main/resources/javaLauncher.rc -o $@


launcher\target:
    cmd /c md $@
```

this is the output of make:

```
/Project/root>/Absolute/Path/to/mingw64\bin\make.exe -f launcher\src\main\scripts\makefile
cmd /c md launcher\target
/Absolute/Path/to/mingw64/bin/g++.exe launcher/src/main/cpp/JavaLauncher.cpp -o launcher/target/JavaLauncher.exe -static -l winpthread
/Absolute/Path/to/mingw64/bin/windres.exe -v -i launcher/src/main/resources/javaLauncher.rc -o launcher/target/JavaLauncher.exe
Using `/Absolute/Path/to/mingw64/bin/gcc -E -xc -DRC_INVOKED  launcher/src/main/resources/javaLauncher.rc'
Using popen to read preprocessor output

/Project/root>
```

this is the result in windows explorer:
[image: exe without specified image]

---

**[edit]**
The final working solution is this:

```
mingwPath = $(realpath Path/to/mingw64/bin)
TARGET_DIR=target
TARGET_OBJECT_DIR=$(TARGET_DIR)/objects
TARGET_DIR_NAME=$(subst /,\, $(TARGET_DIR))
TARGET_OBJECT_DIR_NAME=$(subst /,\, $(TARGET_OBJECT_DIR))
SOURCE_DIR_NAME=src/main
APP_NAME=MyApp
TARGET_BASE_NAME=$(TARGET_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)
TARGET_ARCH=-m32

all: $(TARGET_OBJECT_DIR_NAME) $(TARGET_BASE_NAME).exe


$(TARGET_BASE_NAME).exe: $(TARGET_OBJECT_DIR)/$(APP_NAME).o\ 
 $(TARGET_OBJECT_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)Res.o $(TARGET_OBJECT_DIR_NAME)    
    $(mingwPath)/g++  $(TARGET_ARCH) -o $@ -static -l winpthread   $(filter %.o,$^)

$(TARGET_OBJECT_DIR)/$(APP_NAME).o: $(SOURCE_DIR_NAME)/cpp/$(APP_NAME).cpp
    $(mingwPath)/g++ $(TARGET_ARCH) -c $<  -o $@ 

$(TARGET_OBJECT_DIR)/$(APP_NAME)Res.o:  $(SOURCE_DIR_NAME)/resources/$(APP_NAME).rc
    $(mingwPath)/windres -v -i $< -o $@  --output-format=coff --target=pe-i386


$(TARGET_OBJECT_DIR_NAME):$(TARGET_DIR_NAME)
    echo $@
    cmd /c md $@

$(TARGET_DIR_NAME):
    echo $@
    cmd /c md $@

clean: 
    cmd /c del /s /q $(TARGET_DIR_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the `windres` resource compiler can compile and add the resource data directly to the exe file, but that is what you're trying to do here. Maybe it is possible, I searched a little bit but couldn't find regarding information.

I got this working and having an exe icon. You need to specify the resource object generated by `windres` to the `g++` linker after the program object. Also change the order and have `windres` run first so to have the resource object file generated before `g++` linker links the program and resource objects.

```
all: launcher/target/JavaLauncher.exe

launcher/target/JavaLauncher.exe: launcher/src/main/cpp/JavaLauncher.cpp launcher\target
    /Absolute/Path/to/mingw64/bin/windres.exe -v -i launcher/src/main/resources/JavaLauncher.rc -o launcher/src/main/resources/JavaLauncherRes.o
    /Absolute/Path/to/mingw64/bin/g++.exe $< -o $@ launcher/src/main/resources/JavaLauncherRes.o -static


launcher\target:
    cmd /c md $@
```

[image]

Comment: still not able to confirm since I now ran into a problem with the 32 bit target. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584265/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-after-applying-windes

Comment: Did you try that I told you, to change windres order and the object file it generates? Then add that object file to the g++ linker rigth after the `-o $@`

Comment: yes, the new make file now first creates an *.o file on which windres adds the icon. That is what I got from your answer.

Comment: The makefile you got on the other post is wrong and I still see there you got the windres AFTER the g++ linker commented. I'll check on your error later to see what it is about and I'll update.

Comment: change to `$(mingwPath)/windres -v -i $(SOURCE_DIR_NAME)/resources/$(APP_NAME).rc -o $(TARGET_BASE_NAME)Res.o --output-format=coff --target=pe-i386`

Comment: `$(mingwPath)/g++ -m32 -c $< -o $@ $(TARGET_BASE_NAME)Res.o  -static -l winpthread`

Comment: now I get `target/JavaLauncherRes.o: linker input file unused because linking not done`

Comment: could whe have a short chat please? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/128038/unable-to-add-icon-to-exe-using-windres?tab=general