# Version info .EXE with gcc and windres

Tags: c++, windows, version, codeblocks, windres

I have a problem with version information into a console program. I use Code::Blocks and mingw/gcc, under Windows.
I have two programs. The first (wxWidgets based) have no version problem, all is visible in information window. The second (console) is made following the same way ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/708382/5462378)), but no information is visible in the property window.

This is my resouce.rc file:

```
aaaa ICON "icon.ico"

#include "version.h"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
    FILEVERSION    RC_FILEVERSION
    PRODUCTVERSION RC_FILEVERSION
{
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    {
        BLOCK "040C04E4"
        {
            VALUE "CompanyName",        "Compagny\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription",    "Description\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion",        FULLVERSION_STRING
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     "Copyright (C) 2017\0"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   "program.exe\0"
            VALUE "ProductName",        "Program\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     FULLVERSION_STRING
        }
    }
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    {
        VALUE "Translation", 0x40C, 0x4E4 // French, multilingual
    }
}
```

The icon of the EXE file is good, so the resource file is correctly read by the compiler. No error during windres compilation.

"version.h" is the one generated by Code::Blocks AutoVersioning addon.

What can I do to have this version information visible in property window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to add in the beginning of your .rc file the following header

```
#include "winver.h"
```

and it should work as expected.

Best regards