# When Compiling With .RES File with MinGW G++, .RES isn't Recognized

Tags: c++, windows, icons

I've been trying to compile a program that will have an **icon** linked with it, on **Windows**. Based off of my recent research, *since I've never done this before*, You would make a .RC file with the info of the program, *including icons*, which you would then use **windres** to turn it into a .RES file, which you would then link when compiling:

```
g++ program.cpp -o program.exe
```

would become

```
g++ program.cpp program.res -o program.exe
```

I'm guessing this is the right way to do it, but I'm not sure because when I try to compile the program, it gives the error:

```
program.res: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2.exe error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What can I do to fix this? I've seen people say that if you're compiling 32-bit programs, which I believe I am, you can add parameters to turn it into a .RES file that is meant for compiling 32-bit programs. I've tried this but, it gave the exact same issue, so I don't think that that is the problem.

Comment: What steps exactly did you do to create the `.res` file?

Comment: First, I made a .RC file containing the text: ```id ICON "program.ico"``` and nothing else. Then, I went into the command line, and typed ```windres program.rc -o program.res```. I then typed ```g++ program.cpp program.res -o program.exe```.

Answer (score 6):

Add coff when making the .res

`windres my.rc -O coff my.res`

That's gonna save the .res in a usable format.

I base this on the use of it in a stack overflow post and a quick wiki search.
Also, I had the same issue and adding coff fixed it.
links:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/708382
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF

Answer (score 0):

So on windows you can use the Visual Studio Developer-Powershell.

Create a .rc file (create a .txt file and change the extension).

my.rc

```
iconName ICON "path_to_icon.ico"
```

Compile my.rc to my.rcs.

```
rc my.rc
```

Now you want to link that against your executable. But you cant do that with the .rcs file. You have to convert it with "cvtres" first.

```
cvtres /MACHINE:x64 my.res
```

This results in a file called "my.obj". This file can now be linked when calling g++, for example, just like done above in the question.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/renaming-the-compiled-resource-file

> CVTRES must then be invoked to convert the .res file to a binary
> resource (.rbj) format which can be understood by the linker.

More on the resource compiler included in Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-compiler

Cheers