# C++ Visual studioCode set console icon

Tags: c++, resources, icons

How do I add an **icon** to my console application created in c++ **(Mingw, vscode)** ?

I did some googling but all the answers were for **visual studio** which had a **projects property** to add resource.h,.rc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add an icon to a mingw-gcc compiled executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable)

Comment: Kinda, @Roy2511 i tried the mentioned from the link you provided... but it says {Permission denied...} when i try {g++ -o "Jesvi Bo" my.res}, also tried giving admin permissions, but still no luck ... what  am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Your command looks incorrect.