# How can I change the icon of my EXE file in VS code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, icons

I'm working on a C++ project in VS code, and I've been looking for a way to change the icon for the EXE file from the default to my own ICO file. However, most of the answers I got from searching online were about Visual Studio, which were of no help to me. Could you guys please help me out? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you launching the resource compiler?

Comment: You probably want to read this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable)

Comment: ***I got from searching online were about Visual Studio, which were of no help to me*** It should be some help since the files needed are the same. How the resource compiler gets run is something you will have to setup in VSCode.