# How do I add my own icon into my project in Codelite?

Tags: c++, icons, codelite

I am a beginner at using Codelite IDE for developing my own games in C++. And I was going to find some settings that add my own icon for my game but I cannot find any settings the same as I want. I've looked in the tab "Resources" in project settings. Even I search on the internet but no documents or webs, even from the wiki of Codelite is useful. And I've created a resource script (*.rc) and compiled it again, but nothing happened, just a stupid default executable icon file. Can everybody show me how to add icon for executable file from my project in Codelite?

*Note: I am using Codelite v15.0.11 with MinGW 7.3.0 64 bit and C++.*

Comment: What was the contents of your resource file? Did you compile the resource file into your executable? Please show a [mre]

Comment: I just add ```id ICON "icon.ico"``` in the resource script and I don't know how to compile the resource file and don't know how to write the resource script.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide for creating a resource file:

[How do I add an icon to a mingw-gcc compiled executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable)

Make sure in the .rc file, there is no double quotes, so your path to the icon file probably should not have any space in it

In CodeLite, open the Project Settings (right click, or use the Wrench icon).

On the left, there is a "Linker" item, select it, and on the right, Under "Options", find "Linker Options" entry.  To its right, add your resource file to the end (with a space to separate them).

-mwindows;-O0   my.res