# How do you change the icon that appears in the windows taskbar when running a c++ executable in VSCode

Tags: c++, mingw, rc, ico

I am trying to make custom icons for the file explorer, desktop, and system taskbar view of my program.

I found two resources ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708238/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-mingw-gcc-compiled-executable), [2](https://cplusplus.com/forum/windows/61354/)) that successfully let me set the file explorer and desktop icon (when moving the file onto the desktop), but when I run the program, the icon that appears in the system taskbar is still the default c++ application icon. This is an OpenGL program and I have it set up so it doesn't generate a terminal on running, so the only thing that opens is an openGL window. As stated,  the two resources above led me to create a .rc and .ico file to set up the icon in the places it does appear.

Comment: IIRC the taskbar icon is just the default icon from the applications resource.

Comment: As for the console issue, you need to build your program as a Windows subsystem program, not console. Both MSVC, GCC and Clang have options for that when building (IIRC it's a linker-option).